# Javascript/CSS - Align dynamic content to same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I dynamically generate content blocks that can have each individual number of lines. If they are within a 'record-row' ... I want the 'record-second' within that row to have the same height.

This is for example such a block:

```
 <div class="row record-row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group record-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                     <div class="record-first">
                         <label>Name:</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                     <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... /* Dynamic content LEFT */ ... </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group record-group">
                <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                    <div class="record-first">
                        <label>Adress:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                    <div class="record-second">
                        <p> ... /* Dynamic content RIGHT */ ... </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So for example in the following block ... the left 'record-second' has 2 lines and the right 'record-second' has 4 lines:

```
 <div class="row record-row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group record-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                     <div class="record-first">
                         <label>Name:</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                     <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group record-group">
                <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                    <div class="record-first">
                        <label>Adress:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                    <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I makes sure that the left 'record-second' has the same height as the right 'record-second' and vice versa?

Please keep in mind that they are numerous 'record-row' ... where each record row can have an different height.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oLzq2vhs/

Comment: all your record-first & second in the page have to had same height or just those inside each row (i.e. the right-left pair)?

Comment: ... just those inside each row. ... since each row can have a different height depending on the inner content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/a3eknLuf/
To achieve this you need to;

1. Loop through all the .record-rows
2. When inside, loop through all the .record-second
3. Check the height of each record second and assign it to a variable if it is greater than the previous.
4. Loop again through all the .record-second and assign their height.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var tallestRecordSecond;

  // loop through record rows
  $(".record-row").each(function(){

    tallestRecordSecond = 0;

    // loop through record seconds in this row
    $(this).find(".record-second").each(function(){

        // assign the tallest record second
      if($(this).height() > tallestRecordSecond){
        tallestRecordSecond = $(this).height();
      }
    });

    // loop again and assign the height for each
    $(this).find(".record-second").each(function(){
      $(this).height(tallestRecordSecond);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jerdine. A minor adjustment if possible, the last two blocks ('record-row') now also have the height of the first one. Is it possible to set the height of each block depending on its individual inner height?

Comment: @PhilippM apologies, I updated the fiddle. The last line of the code is incorrect. It should be `$(this).find(".record-second").each(function(){
      $(this).height(tallestRecordSecond);
    });` Their parent divs should resize properly now.

Answer (score 0):

To try to help you I used only CSS. The solution I adopted involves the use of flexbox

Bootstrap has different classes to manage flexbox and you can see them [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)

Since using them would have added several classes to your divs, I decided to use only CSS, so it's easier for you to understand the various additions I've made.

Nothing prevents you from throwing away my CSS rules by managing them using Bootstrap classes (i.e. `.d-flex`, `.h-100`, `.flex-column`, `m-0`...). The important thing here is understand what's going on and, for my personal opinion, seeing the rules on CSS only is more understandible.

I didn't touch your layout. These are the rules I added:

```
.form-horizontal,
.record-second,
.record-group {
    height: 100%; /*set these div to 100% to take full advantage of flexbox*/
}

.record-group {
    display: flex; /* create a flexbox container */
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
}

.col-sm-4.record-col {
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* the first div can't grow or shrink*/
}

.col-sm-8.record-col {
    flex: 1 0 auto; /* the second div can grow to fill all the space*/
}
```

```css
.row {
 background: #f8f9fa;
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 /* I added also this line */
}

.col {
 border: solid 1px #6c757d;
 padding: 10px;
}

.record-first {
 padding-top: 12px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 border-top: #ffffff medium solid;
 border-left: #ffffff 0px solid;
 border-right: #ffffff 0px solid;
}

.record-second {
 padding-top: 12px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 border-top: #ffffff medium solid;
 border-left: #ffffff 4px solid;
 border-right: #ffffff 4px solid;
}

/* --------------------------- */
/* I added these lines of code */
/* --------------------------- */

.form-horizontal,
.record-second,
.record-group {
 height: 100%;
}

.record-group {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin: 0;
}

.col-sm-4.record-col {
 flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.col-sm-8.record-col {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
}


/* --------------------------- */
/* I added these lines of code */
/* --------------------------- */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
 <div class="row record-row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group record-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                     <div class="record-first">
                         <label>Name:</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                     <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group record-group">
                <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                    <div class="record-first">
                        <label>Adress:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                    <div class="record-second ">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="row record-row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <form class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group record-group">
                 <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                     <div class="record-first">
                         <label>Name:</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                     <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group record-group">
                <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                    <div class="record-first">
                        <label>Adress:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                    <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row record-row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <form class="form-horizontal h-100">
             <div class="form-group record-group h-100">
                 <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                     <div class="record-first">
                         <label>Name:</label>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                     <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group record-group">
                <div class="col-sm-4 record-col">
                    <div class="record-first">
                        <label>Adress:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 record-col">
                    <div class="record-second">
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                         <p> ... </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```